# How to Identify records which are having the error while inserting multiple records using JSON and Node JS

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to insert multiple records in Posgresql database using Node JS application.

The records are passed in the JSON format as key value pair. I am getting an expected error as I am passing column value - fcr_process_date__c as "" in the data JSON. But the error response is not helping me in identifying which Row out of the JSON or which record out of the multiple records is throwing the error. Below is the sample JSON data which we are trying to insert and below that is the code which we are using to perform that operation .

Data:

```json
[
{"casenumber":"2011-134723365","fcr_process_date__c":"","id":"5005E000008gT4LQAU"},
{"casenumber":"2011-134723364","fcr_process_date__c":"2020-11-30T13:31:11.000Z","id":"5005E000008gT4KQAU"}
]
```

Code:

```
try{
        let data = JSON.stringify(records);
        pool.connect()
        .then(client => {
            return client.query('INSERT INTO salesforce.case SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset (NULL::salesforce.case,\''+data+'\') RETURNING id') // your query string here
              .then(res => {
                client.release()
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // your callback here
              })
              .catch(e => {
                client.release()
                console.log(e) // your callback here
              })
        })
    }catch(e){
        //client.end();
    }
```

I am getting the below error response which is having no details about the record which is getting failed
during the INSERT process :-

```
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147410+00:00 app[web.1]: error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147413+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147413+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147414+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147414+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147415+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147415+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147416+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147416+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147416+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147417+00:00 app[web.1]: length: 109,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147418+00:00 app[web.1]: severity: 'ERROR',
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147418+00:00 app[web.1]: code: '22007',
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147418+00:00 app[web.1]: detail: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147419+00:00 app[web.1]: hint: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147419+00:00 app[web.1]: position: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147419+00:00 app[web.1]: internalPosition: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147420+00:00 app[web.1]: internalQuery: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147420+00:00 app[web.1]: where: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147420+00:00 app[web.1]: schema: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147421+00:00 app[web.1]: table: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147421+00:00 app[web.1]: column: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147421+00:00 app[web.1]: dataType: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147422+00:00 app[web.1]: constraint: undefined,
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147422+00:00 app[web.1]: file: 'datetime.c',
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147422+00:00 app[web.1]: line: '3761',
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147423+00:00 app[web.1]: routine: 'DateTimeParseError'
2020-12-15T19:22:52.147423+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

What is the best way to identify records throwing error or Failed records while inserting large number of data into postgresql table using Node JS app

Comment: how do you get multiple records before insert? I think better verify them before.

Comment: Hi @DaniilLoban , I am getting those records through Salesforce BULK API 2.0 in a csv format and I am parsing them to JSON format to insert in postgresql . Issue is not about records not getting inserted , but infact it is more about the approach . If I am inserting 6 records at once and 4th record is having the error , then how can we identify this 4th record from the Error Response so that i can insert these error details into a separate table ?

Comment: Hi @Devam, I understand. But why you can't check records when converts them from csv?

Comment: if you got error invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
you'll need do something with fcr_process_date__c":"" (get positions of records with this empty string) in your data
It that your question?  I think that postgresql can't fix it itself (maybe it works like one transaction)

Comment: Hi @DaniilLoban , I can definitely fix that error in many ways . But my concern is that in future  there might be many other errors which can come up at runtime , so how can we identify that which particular record is causing the error out of the many records which I am inserting .

Comment: Hi @Devam, I think you need make validator with rules for each field whitch can arise error.
I can't say more because I don't see your code,